# Display product text attribute on category

Tags: category, product-attribute, magento1.7.0.2

I'm trying to display a product text attribute on category list or view mode, but i can't find a guide to do this.

For example, a Product have this Text attribute: "7 work days to delivery" in the product page, i want to display "7 works days to delivery" on category page in both type of view.

How can i find .phtml file to add this code:

```
<div class="tempi-spedizione" >
                                <table >
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $this->__('Shipping Time Delivery') ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td rowspan="2" class="center imgspedizioni">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/tempi-spedizione.png') ?>" alt="tempi-spedizione" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $_product->getData('tempi_spedizione') ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
```

I find this code on product page.

There is an example page of the product:
http://www.millstore.it/formevet-antiparassitario-fiprotix-spot-on-cani-giganti-da-40-a-60-kg-4-fiale

And the category is this:
http://www.millstore.it/animali/cani/antiparassitari/pipette-spot-on

I want to display the text attribute under the price or the title of product in both view.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your attribute code in the `list.phtml` file there you can find both view , `Grid` & `List`. 
File path is `app\design\frontend\YourPackageName\YourThemeName\template\catalog\product`

You can find `title or price` section there and can execute your code their to get your `attribute` data on `category page`

Let me know if you need more help on this. I would love to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, the attribute doesn't display under the product or any other part of the page.

Comment: can you send me your list.phtml file so maybe i can see, Also you can have chat with me on skype, amalik62

Comment: I search your nickname on Skype but i can't find you. How can i send the list.phtml trought stackexchange?

Comment: email at magento@magentoxpert.com

Comment: I have send you the file. Thanks for your help